# Real world applications of post-1950s High Energy Physics

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question, applied-physics

Imagine a world where people knew everything we know today except for high energy physics, where their knowledge ends at our ~1950s level. Is there any real world application, any particular piece of technology, that we currently have or that is under development, they would not have because of their lack of knowledge?

To be more precise: In this fictional world, people for example know QED, renormalization and Feynman rules, but they do not know QCD, the particle zoo, the Standard Model and beyond. However, they have developed things like topological methods in condensed matter, as well as the world wide web independently, without doing research in particle physics. Also, I would not count applications such as positron emission tomography, because the ideas from particle physics it relies on predate 1950s.

Comment: This is a tough question. I can't answer it.

Comment: The superminds at Fermilab thought about this too, and apparently did not find anything worth beyond this (no actual technology that purely belongs to the QCD realm, apparently): http://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/particle-physics/benefits/index.html

Comment: Some kind of more sophisticated tomography such as the one used in the recently announced project to scan the Giza pyramids would qualify? I don't really know http://www.forbes.com/sites/alanboyle/2015/10/21/egypt-lays-out-plan-to-scan-for-secrets-of-the-pyramids-with-cosmic-rays/

Comment: Although the list of direct applications might be short, the indirect effects might be substantial. You could ask in a similar manner that "What was the benefit of NASA, assuming we would have satellites anyway?"

Comment: @MikaelKuisma I agree with you, and my question was not meant to diminish the importance of research in HEP. I am just genuinely interested in examples of those direct applications.

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question.

Comment: I do not really understand why this question has been flagged as "too broad". Judging by the replies so far, it does not seem there are "too many possible answers". Furthermore, I think such lists of applications can be interesting, and have been compiled for example in mathematics, see e.g.: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2556/real-world-applications-of-mathematics-by-arxiv-subject-area http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62866/recent-applications-of-mathematics